# Binding 2 dropdownlist with LINQ

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, drop-down-menu

Im stuck in my project here and i really need some help!
I have 2 dropdownlists "DropDownPostal" and "DropDownCity". When the user/employee logges into the system, he gets the list of Postals in the first dropdown list. Lets say he choose a postal and tabs over to the second dropdown "city". I want city to be updated with the postal the user choose earlier. I have everything working with the login and retrieving data from the database to the DropDownPostal. But I cannot get the other DropDownCity updated with any data!

Here is my code for the event i made for the postaldropdown, Im trying to make a "onLeave" event.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
   using System.Web.UI;
   using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 namespace Test
  {
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    // Entity
    DanxWebsiteEntities dwe = new DanxWebsiteEntities();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        //Dropdown postback
        //DropDownListPostal.AutoPostBack = false;

        //Sessions
        if (Session["UserID"] == null && Session["Name"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            msg1.Text = "User id: "+Session["UserID"].ToString();
            msg2.Text = "User Name: " + Session["Name"].ToString();
        }   
        //Update dropdownpostal
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Guid is structure type 
            Guid id =(Guid) Session["UserID"];
            DropDownListPostal.DataSource = (from custumAdr in dwe.VW_CustumAddress
                                             where custumAdr.UserID ==(Guid)id
                                             select custumAdr).ToList();
            DropDownListPostal.DataTextField = "Postal";
            DropDownListPostal.DataValueField = "UserID";
            DropDownListPostal.DataBind();
        }
    }



    protected void DropDownListPostal_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var data in dwe.VW_CustumAddress)
            if (data.Postal == DropDownListPostal.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                DropDownListBy.Text = data.City;

            }
            else
            {

            }
    }
    }

}
```

Im not even sure if this code is close to correct.
Detailed help with code will be much appreciated.

Cheers :-)

Comment: Have you Checked **DropDownListPostal** AutoPostback to **True**?

Comment: If possible show here design page code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you only need to change the value displayed in `dropDownListCity` according to the value selected in `dropDownListPostal`. To do so, you need to bind both dropdown lists in `Page_Load` and then handle the selected index when `SelectedIndexChanged` is triggered.

```
private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetData()
{
    using(var dataContext = new DbEntities())
    {
        return dataContext.VW_CustumAddress 
            .ToList() 
            .Select(item => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item.Postal, item.City))
            .ToArray();
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostback)
    {
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> data = GetData();
        //Bind Postal dropdown list
        dropDownListPostal.DataSource = data.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();
        // ^ Select only 'Postal' column in dropdown list.
        dropDownListPostal.DataBind();
        // Bind City dropdown list
        // We need to bind to a key-value pair to know the correspondence between items
        dropDownListCity.DataValueField = "Key";
        dropDownListCity.DataTextField = "Value";
        dropDownListCity.DataSource = data;
        dropDownListCity.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Now, after you bound your controls to data you only need to handle `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `dropDownListPostal` (don't forget to set `AutoPostback="true"` in the markup of `dropDownListPostal`).
**EDIT**: Before selecting an item, clear the selection of your dropdown list to make sure only one item is selected.

```
protected void OnDropDownListPostalSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dropDownListCity.ClearSelection();
    var postal = dropDownListPostal.SelectedValue;
    var listItem = dropDownListCity.Items.FindByValue(postal);
    listItem.Selected = true;
}
```

That should do it. Hope it helps.

Comment: The soultion was great but i still have some errors, The first one is I cannot have multiplay data in a dropdown, i solved that by saying clearselection();
Now I can see all the City Names on the DropBoxCity but when i choose between others postalt, then the DropBoxCity Does not update and my the DropDownPostal just refresh and keep going back to the first value in dropdown index..

Comment: this is the error: Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList

Comment: @SaiefAl-Faour, please see the latest edit - it should not give you the error with multiple selection.

Comment: I have done that already :-) thanks
But this line here is blocking me from logging in:

     dropDownListCity.DataValueField = "Key"; // here i put UserID
     dropDownListCity.DataTextField = "Value"; // here i put City
     dropDownListCity.DataSource = data; 
     dropDownListCity.DataBind();

Comment: the error is: Error: DataBinding: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' does not contain a property with the name 'City'.

Comment: @SaiefAl-Faour, **Value** is the name of the property whose value is displayed in the dropdown list. Since `KeyValuePair<T,V>` does not contain a property named **City** you get the error.

Comment: I have one more question. Besides the CityDropDown that i want to be updated, I also have 2 textboxes with "name" and "street" which i also want to be udpdated with same data i choose from PostaldropDown. And is it possible to make LINQ/ Select,Where etc so i can maniplulate more with my data, like i do in the first example i posted?

best regards

Comment: @SaiefAl-Faour, to update textboxes, just add `textBoxName.Text = postal;` and `textBoxStreet.Text = postal;` in `OnDropDownListPostalSelectedIndexChanged`. As for the second question is unclear.

Comment: i think i explained it in a unclear way. In my database i still have other columns besides the city and postal, Like "Street and Name" Which i also want to display.
textBoxStreet.Text = postal;//diplay the postal number again.
I want somehow to add more items in the .Select(item => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item.Postal, item.City)).

Comment: Maybe something like a listbox to display all the streets, (similar to the dropdown)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17174/discussion-between-repierre-and-saief-al-faour)

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure DropDownListPostal has AutoPostBack = True
2. You have no DropDownListPostal.DataBind() in your code, so the data you're assigning to it is not being bound. Make sure this is called after the data is assigned with the .DataSource.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned here

```
//Dropdown postback
//DropDownListPostal.AutoPostBack = false;
```

Please make it True.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListPostal" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListPostal_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Instead of using **DropDownListBy.Text = data.City;**

You can select Dropdown list by Value also,.

```
 DropDownListBy.SelectedValue = data.id
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Hi Rahul, I have done that and still get nothing. What happens basically now is that i can see all the postal data on DropDownPostal no problem there! But when I for instance choose postal "234345" the post back does not update DropDownCity with any City names (it is still empty)

Comment: Instead of using **DropDownListBy.Text = data.City;** Try by using **DropDownListBy.SelectedValue = data.id**

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
 //You must bind your datas before set Text Value
 DropDownListBy.DataSource =...;
 DropDownListBy.DataBind();

 DropDownListBy.Text = data.City;
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.text.aspx

Or you can also

```
 DropDownListBy.Items.Add(data.City);
```

Comment: I belive I have done that already, you can see that i posted all the code now :)